Exaggerated sine value offset for mesh.position vs normal integer
In the animate function, the following code understandably keeps oscillating the value of i between 1 and 3:
let i = 2;
i += Math.sin( time );
console.log(i); // output 1 ... 3

But why does using the same logic on mesh.position, originally at [0,0,0], exaggerate the 'oscillated' x/y/z value between 0 and around 285 on a plane of height 2 units?
mesh.position.y += Math.sin(time)
console.log(mesh.position.y); // Output 0 .... 285 and back to 0

How can I make it work on a mesh with position.y at say, 5, and it keeps oscillating between 4 and 6?
mesh.position.y = Math.sin(time) won't do in this case as it will reset the y value between -1 and 1.

Obviously, += will cause the sine values to pile up. I'd suggest mesh.position.y = 5 + Math.sin(time);

@RuudHelderman Thanks a lot. Your solution makes sense. But just curious to know why it doesn't pile up in case of simple integers or floats?

I assume you are referring to let i = 2; i += Math.sin( time ); There you re-initialize i on every iteration. Notice those two statements together are equivalent to let i = 2 + Math.sin( time );

@RuudHelderman Ohh. Thank you so much. Makes sense. Could you please share your comment as the answer so I select it as chosen? :)
